# CSV File read doesn't care about quotes

Tags: bash, csv

I have a csv file that contains much information and I need to create a script that creates posts in wordpress with information in that file. For most information it's ok but I'm blocked with a column that contains text value with `,`.

Here is an exemple of the columns that fail :

`other_information,"my text, my other text",other_information`

The script :

```
  list_posts="$(wp post list --post_type=post --field=ID)"
  loop=0;
  while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12 col13 col14 col15 col16 col17 col18 col19 col20 col21 col22
  do
    if [ "$loop" != "0" ]
    then
      update=0;
      if [ "$list_posts" != "" ]
      then
        for post in $list_posts
        do
          reference_agence="$(wp post meta get $post wpcf-reference-agence)";
          if [ "$reference_agence" = "$col2" ]
          then
            update=1;
            wp post meta update $post wpcf-reference-agence $col2;
            wp post meta update $post wpcf-type-d-annonce $col3;
            wp post meta update $post wpcf-type-bien $col4;
            wp post meta update $post wpcf-code-post $col5;
            wp post meta update $post wpcf-ville $col6;
            wp post meta update $post wpcf-property-location "$col21";
            echo "Update $post réalisé";
          fi
        done
      fi
      if [ "$update" = "0" ]
      then
        post="$(wp post create --post_title="$col1" --post_content="$col2" --post_author=1 --post_type=post --post_status=publish --porcelain)";
        wp post meta update $post wpcf-reference-agence $col2;
        wp post meta update $post wpcf-type-d-annonce $col3;
        wp post meta update $post wpcf-type-bien $col4;
        wp post meta update $post wpcf-code-post $col5;
        wp post meta update $post wpcf-ville $col6;
        wp post meta update $post wpcf-property-location "$col8";
       echo "Création $post réalisé";
      fi
    else
      loop=1;
    fi
  done < annonces.csv
```

Col21 is the problem in the database I only have `"my text` and in col22 `my other text"`. So what's the problem in my script?

Answer (score 0):

If you use awk, you can use the awk variable `FPAT` in order to specify how to parse fields from a line. This will allow you to access columns by `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ...

```
line='other_information,"my text, my other text",other_information'
echo $line | awk -vFPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '{ printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", $1, $2, $3); }'
```

Would print

```
other_information
"my text, my other text"
other_information
```

Then you can use this to read all of the fields (either by printing each on their own line and having several `read` calls, or by writing a small awk script to do this instead of bash).

Comment: With your code, i had this : other_information,"my
text,
my

Comment: Which version of awk are you using? I think the `FPAT` variable was added in Gnu awk 4. You might need to change it to `gawk` and make sure its version >=4

Comment: It's ok now but if I have a multiple row and I want just one data from a specific row and specific columns, how ca I do it ?

Comment: awk has the special variable `NR` which is the 1-based current line number. So if you say "NR==3 { print $2, $4 }" that's the same as saying "the second and fourth fields of line 3", or "NR >= 7 && NR <= 20 { print $6 }" is "print the sixth field from all lines 7-20"